# Delegate Pattern In Swift w/o Segue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, delegates

I cannot find an example of the Swift Delegate pattern without the segue included. I want the boss class(boss view) to send orders to the worker class(worker view) and print what the boss says to print. The Delegate is coming up 'nil' when I press either of the buttons (doThisButton/doThatButton) on the boss page.

**Edit: My Views are set up as follows: the 'TheBoss' VC has three buttons, 'doThisButton', 'doThatButton', and 'goToTheWorker' button. the 'TheWorker' VC has a text box. The 'doThisButton'/'doThatButton' send information to the text box in 'TheWorker' VC, but do not make 'TheWorker' VC appear. the 'goToTheWorker' button is a show segue that was set up in storyboard to open the 'TheWorker' VC.**

This is the 'Boss' class

```
import UIKit

protocol TheBossesOrdersDelegate {
    func doThis(numberOne: Int, stringOne: String)
    func doThat(numberTwo: Int, stringTwo: String)
}

class TheBoss: UIViewController {

    // Declair Delegate
    var delegate: TheBossesOrdersDelegate!

    @IBAction func doThisButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        delegate.doThis(numberOne: 75, stringOne: "Do This")
    }
    @IBAction func doThatButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        delegate.doThat(numberTwo: 125, stringTwo: "Do That")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

This is the 'Worker' class

```
import UIKit

class TheWorker: UIViewController, TheBossesOrdersDelegate {

    let theBoss = TheBoss()

    func doThis(numberOne: Int, stringOne: String) {
        print("the boss send this number to print: \(numberOne) and this string: \(stringOne)")
        theWorkersTextBox.text = "Number: \(numberOne) String:\(stringOne)"
    }

    func doThat(numberTwo: Int, stringTwo: String) {
        print("the boss send this number to print: \(numberTwo) and this string: \(stringTwo)")
        theWorkersTextBox.text = "Number: \(numberTwo) String:\(stringTwo)"
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var theWorkersTextBox: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        theBoss.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Comment: How is the Worker VC being created and presented? Or the Boss VC?  Which is first and how are they connected?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html

Comment: both are embedded in a navigation controller, the boss is presented first and contains a button that connects to the worker via a show segue.

Comment: Wait, what? The boss crates the worker? Then why do you have code in your `TheWorker` class that creates a new instance of theBoss? That makes no sense.

Comment: Your question and your comments contradict each other. You need to describe your problem more clearly or we can't help you.

Comment: while looking for 'delegate pattern' examples online, I've only been able to find examples that included a segue transition within the functionality of the delegate method. In hindsight it probably was not needed, just confused the situation.

Comment: The way I would like for this to function is to have my boss view controller send the information to the worker view controller, however I don't want the show segue (that brings up the worker VC) to be linked with this delegate functionality. I have a button on the Boss VC that links to the worker VC, however I do not want this to be connected to the delegate.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code has the worker create the boss. Since you do that, you need to tell the boss who it's delegate is:

```
import UIKit

class TheWorker: UIViewController, TheBossesOrdersDelegate {


    let theBoss = { 
      let result = TheBoss()
      result.delegate = self  //This is the line you are missing
      return result
    }()

//The rest of your TheWorker class's code...
}
```

### EDIT:

Based on your comment, you have a confused mess. Post the Boss class code for the button that displays a worker view controller. And your title says "w/o segue", but then in your comment you say "the boss is presented first and contains a button that connects to the worker **via a show segue**." What? you said without a segue.